# Is it possible to calculate share price previous to stock split based on adjusted close price?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, stock-analysis, stock-split

The price of NSE:HDFCBANK was around Rs. 2K+ before it split on [19-Sep-2019](https://www.moneycontrol.com/company-facts/hdfcbank/splits/hdf01). I am using [AlphaVantage](https://www.alphavantage.co/) to get stock price for NSE:HDFCBANK. It does not show the stock price before stock split as Rs. 2K+. Below is the data I get from AlphaVantage.

Is there a way for me to calculate the share price before share split based on below data? If not, what is additional data I need?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a traditional stock split, the number of shares increases by the split ratio and share price decreases by the inverse of that ratio.

For example, you own 100 shares of XYZ at $100 and a 2:1 split occurs.   The post split position will be 200 shares at $50.  The value of the position is unchanged since 100 x $100 = 200 x $50.

To reverse engineer the data, apply the inverse of the split numbers.  If historical data shows that the close was $50 the day before a 2:1 split, then the actual close was $100.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So the data I have (screenshot) does not mention this, right? I do have the number of shares post split.

Comment: The data that you provided in your screenshot is of no use because the adjusted close equals the close.  Therefore there has been no adjustment so there's nothing to reverse engineer.  If you had the entire data history since the split and there were adjustments due to  dividends, you could reverse engineer all of this.

Comment: @BobBaerker I interpret it differently -- even the "unadjusted" close has been adjusted for splits. This is commonplace because charts typically use the unadjusted close, which is considered okay despite dividends (as long as they are fairly small) but would be very misleading if it failed to account for splits. So OP's data are suitable to follow exactly the process you describe to find a *truly* unadjusted close -- which will indeed be about Rs2000 before the split